# How to hide my Windows VPS IP on outgoing http requests?

Tags: windows-server-2012, reverse-proxy

I have a windows VPS running a web app behind Cloudflare. The app needs to initiate outbound connections based on user actions (eg upload image from URL).

How can I prevent my server IP from being discovered with these outgoing requests? Is there a way to proxy or route these requests through a different IP address or service?

If possible, a simple beginner-friendly solution would suit best.

EDIT: this is to prevent DDOS attacks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by "hiding" your IP address?

Comment: @Michael Hampton Attackers can DDOS a server directly (bybassing cloudflare) if they have the origin server's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Fire up another VPS somewhere, install forward proxy software, and then configure your application to use that server as a web proxy.

Keep in mind that open proxies are **bad**, so make sure to put in place firewall rules such that only your server can make requests to the proxy.

Comment: any  forward proxy software recommendations for windows server 2012 ?